# hMailServer, triggers jar failed

Tags: vbscript, jar, command-prompt, hmail-server

I wrote a little VBscript that calls a JAR-file over a command-line.

When I double-click on the VBscript file it runs, as it should. I am logged in with a administrator account.

```
    call testSub()
    Sub testSub()
    CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "java -jar " & "c:\test\UntisSMTP_SMS.jar " & "aaaa ", 0, true
    End Sub
```

but when `hMailServer` ( run as local system )  should call the jar, nothing happens and I get a error message

> Script Error: Source: (null) - Error: 80004005

I googled the error and I found a hint that, the problem comes from not valid access rights

Is there a way, how hMailServer can start the jar ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_80004005.htm This might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but could not find a solution there.

Comment: Try to run the program as an administrator. See if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

WORKAROUND:

I didn't find a direct answer to my problem, but I wanna share my workaround-solution.
hMailserver can not run a command prompt line, even if the services runs under a administrator account. I didn't find out why.

So my solution was to write a VBscript that sends a HTTPPost with the E-Mailbody to a PHP script, then the PHPscript replace my JAVA Program.